# Alice Fixture: Reference to entity already persisted & flush

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, nelmio-alice

I simplified my problem with an exemple of a theoretical `Article` entity.
My Article has a title, content category and a type

My fixtures are writed in separates YAML files

```
# category.yml
AppBundle\Entity\Category:
    category_1:
        id: 1
        name: foo
    category_2:
        id: 2
        name: bar


# type.yml
AppBundle\Entity\Type:
    type_1:
        id: 1
        name: baz
    type_2:
        id: 2
        name: qux

# article.yml
AppBundle\Entity\Article:
    article_1:
        id: 1
        title: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur"
        content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur"
        category: '@category_1'
```

The problem is I have a DoctrineListener on `Events::preUpdate` which update Article::type depends of Article::Category

```
/**
* Doctrine Listener
*/
class ArticleListener
{
   // ...
    private function preUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $article = $args->getEntity();

        // Get type from DB
        $type = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Type')->find(1)

        $article->setType($type);
    }
}
```

So load category & type fixtures first

```
class BasicFixtures extends Fixture
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $files = [
            'category' => __DIR__.'/../../../AppBundle/DataFixtures/category.yml',
            'type'     => __DIR__.'/../../../AppBundle/DataFixtures/type.yml',
            //... other yml files
        ];

        $loader    = new NativeLoader();
        $objectSet = $loader->loadFiles($files);

        foreach ($objectSet->getObjects() as $key => $object) {
            $this->addReference($key, $object);
            $manager->persist($object);
        }

        $manager->flush();
    }
}
```

And then I load my Article fixture with `DependentFixtureInterface::getDependencies` to be sure categories and types are already loaded

```
class ArticleFixtures extends Fixture implements DependentFixtureInterface
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        // This give me my object
        dump($this->getReference('category_1'));


        $files = [
            'article' => __DIR__.'/../../../AppBundle/DataFixtures/article.yml',
            //... other yml files
        ];

        $loader    = new NativeLoader();
        $objectSet = $loader->loadFiles($files);

        foreach ($objectSet->getObjects() as $key => $object) {
            $manager->persist($object);
        }

        $manager->flush();
    }

    public function getDependencies()
    {
        return [
            BasicFixtures::class,
        ];
    }
}
```

But it seams with that, the reference of "@category_1" is lost

```
In FixtureNotFoundExceptionFactory.php line 23:

  [Nelmio\Alice\Throwable\Exception\Generator\Resolver\FixtureNotFoundException]  
  Could not find the fixture "category_1".
```

What did I do wrong?
Many thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

you have to name your reference in BasicFixture.

```
// other fixtures can get this object using the 'admin-user' name
$this->addReference('category_1', $userAdmin);
```

And then get that reference in ArticleFixture with the name given.

```
$object->addCategory($this->getReference('category_1'));
$manager->persist($object);
```

For reference:

> Sharing Objects between Fixtures:

https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html#sharing-objects-between-fixtures

> Loading the Fixture Files in Order:

https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html#loading-the-fixture-files-in-order

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already read that. But the problem il I load my objects with YAM files

I don't know which category will be used. It could be category_1, category_2 or whatever. I could also be an other field


     // Do that is only if my fixtures are done in PHP
     $object->addCategory($this->getReference('category_1'));

All my references already exist when I load my article.yml but the 
`NativeLoader->loadFiles()` seems to not be awear of it

Comment: I edited my post to show you that the reference is existing in ArticleFixture.php but not find by NativeLoader

Comment: I don't use date actually. But I could use <(new \DateTime('2014-02-02'))>